# Change paths of multiple images inserted as links

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I have a document, in which there are multiple images inserted as links, i.e. through **Insert > Picture > From file > Link = [v]**.

The overall file structure looks like this:

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test\
                      |-- test.odt
                      |-- image1.png
                      |-- image2.png
```

And now I want to move the files from "Test" directory to "Images". That is:

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\Test\
                      |-- test.odt
                      |-- Images\
                          |-- image1.png
                          |-- image2.png
```

And by that reason, the links in document are now broken and need to be fixed.

This assuming there are about 30 images in document, and I want to fix their paths automatically, instead of manually. How it could be done?

I use OpenOffice 4.1.3, but I believe, this task is the same in both Open and Libre office suits.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the property `GraphicURL` of the objects on the `Drawpage` of that Writer file...

What have you tried?
What's not working?